# Shareplum: Authentication error [AADSTS50126]

Tags: python, sharepoint, shareplum

recently I have been facing authentication issues with Shareplum library (to be precise it's since Friday 4th November 2022)

The following is my code:

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365    
from shareplum.site import Version

website = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com"    
List_Name = 'Start'

sharepointUsername = "xxxxxxxxxx"    
sharepointPassword = "xxxxxxxxxx" 

authcookie = Office365(website, username=sharepointUsername,   
password=sharepointPassword).GetCookies()

site = Site(sharepointSite, version=Version.v2016, authcookie=authcookie)
```

The code was working well until last Thursday 3rd November 2022; no changes or modification was made to the code. There's no MFA enabled it's a single point authentication, I have seen that Shareplum has problem with MFA but I don't have that enabled and still this error persists.

Now I'm stuck with this error:

```
Exception: ('Error authenticating against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', 'AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.')
```

can someone please help me out on tackling this problem?

```
error authenticating against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', 'AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password
```

Comment: Could it be that the password for the user you are using has expired (so you need to change it)? Have you tried to log in using these credentials manually, that is?

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I have no problem logging in manually with my credentials. I have also changed my password to try it but turned to be futile.

Comment: While MFA seems as a problem, the other one might be "blocking legacy authentication", which is achieved in the Conditional Access Blade of AAD. You can check this link for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/block-legacy-authentication#block-legacy-authentication 
If a conditional access policy is blocking any legacy user authentication then a warning would come up each time the user tried to authenticate. Please check it and let us know. I had come around this problem once in the past too. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/297589/78095

Comment: @jimas13 sorry for the late reply. I went through the link you suggested to check if there was any blocking of legacy authentication and found it wasn't. I couldn't warp around this issue so I switched to using Office-365 library instead of shareplum to work with sharepoint